# Dynamic component creation in ember@2.10.0

Tags: ember.js

I have this piece of code in an addon that worked before Glimmer was introduced but is now failing since updating to ember@2.10.0.

```
        const self = this;

        ....

        const el = document.createElement('div');
        Ember.Component.create({
          model: model,
          layout: self.get('suggestionTemplate'),
        }).appendTo(el);
        return el;
```

I am now getting the following error

> ember.debug.js:8722 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'hasRegistration' of undefined(…)

This is happening because the owner is "undefined" deep within the ember code when running the "hasHelper" function.

[image]

Is there something I can pass to the component creation to prevent this happening or is there a better way to do this?  Essentially I need the RAW DOM for a third party API.

### UPDATE

If `model` in the above code is an `ember-data` model everything works fine.  If it is a string or Ember.Object it crashes.

Comment: What Ember version were you on previously? I believe this was never a public API.

Comment: This was recommended by rwjblue at the time as described  [here](https://github.com/aupac/ember-aupac-typeahead/issues/23).  I am happy to change to a different way if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working by putting the result into an Ember Object. And injecting the parent renderer into the component.  It appears that both were required to get this working.

```
        const self = this;

        ....

        const el = document.createElement('div');
        if (typeof model !== 'object') {
          model = Ember.Object.create({
            displayName: model
          });
        }
        Component.create({
          model,
          layout: self.get('suggestionTemplate'),
          renderer: self.renderer
        }).appendTo(el);
        return el;
```

Comment: Can you accept this as the answer so it doesn't show up as not having an answer? Thanks!